# The exactness of a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a quotation:

> **Corollary 3.7.12** If $\Gamma$ is a non-amenable residually finite group, then $C^{*}(\Gamma)$ is not exact.
>
> It follows from this corollary that $B(l^{2})$ is not exact either (since exactness passes to subalgebras).

**My question is: How to use the corollary to judge $B(l^{2})$ is not exact?**

A discrete group $\Gamma$ is called *residually finite* if  there exist subgroups $\Gamma\supset\Gamma_{1}\supset\Gamma_{2}\supset...$ such that each $\Gamma_{i}$ is a finite-index, normal subgroup of $\Gamma$ and $\bigcap_{n}\Gamma_{n}=\{e\}$(the neutral element of $\Gamma$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From earlier in the book you know that $\mathbb F_2$ is countable, non amenable, and residually finite. By the Corollary, $C^*(\mathbb F_2)$ is not exact. It is also separable, so it embeds in $B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$. If $B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ were exact, then so would be all of its subalgebras, contradicting the fact that $C^*(\mathbb F_2)$ is not exact.

Comment: But, I do not know why $C^{*}(\mathbb{F_{2}})$ can be embeds in $B(l^{2}(\mathbb(N)))$?

Comment: Any separable C*-algebra $A$ embeds in $B(\ell^2 (\mathbb N)) $. Because it has a faithful state,  which you can use for GNS. The Hilbert space you get will be separable (because $A$ is separable), so isomorphic to $\ell^2 (\mathbb N) $.